# Display sub array of a document in MongoDB as table in php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

i am developing a web application in PHP with MongoDB as Database.

Currently I have the following Document in the MongoDB database.

```
{
  _id : 1,
  name:"Rahul",
  STD:"10th",
  marks:[
    {
        subject:"English",
        mark_secured:"75",
        Grade:"B+"
    },
    {
        subject:"Science",
        mark_secured:"84",
        Grade:"A"
    },
    {
        subject:"Mathematics",
        mark_secured:"65",
        Grade:"B"
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id : 2,
  name:"James",
  STD:"9th",
  marks:[
    {
        subject:"English",
        mark_secured:"83",
        Grade:"A"
    },
    {
        subject:"Science",
        mark_secured:"94",
        Grade:"A+"
    },
    {
        subject:"Mathematics",
        mark_secured:"78",
        Grade:"B+"
    }
 ]
}
```

Database name : Student
Collection name : stdMark
I have listed the names of the students and class as an hyperlink in a table. when i click on any student, i want to list the marks of the student in a table in the following format in another page.

```
||=======================================||
|| Subject      | Mark Secured  | Grade  ||
||--------------|---------------|--------||
|| English      | 83            | A      ||
|| Science      | 94            | A+     ||
|| Mathematics  | 78            | B+     ||
||=======================================||
```

Please help me to fetch and display the sub array values and display it in table format in PHP.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: right now i have displayed the name of the sudents using following code....

Comment: foreach($mark->find() as $item){
        echo '<div>'.$item->name.'</div>';
    }

Comment: i tried to access the mark using the folloing code. But didnt worked.

Comment: foreach($mark->find(['name' => 'Rahul']) as $item){
        echo '<div>'.$item->marks->mark_secured.'</div>';
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:
```

$id = $_GET['student_id']

```
$cursor = Student.stdMark.find({_id : $id})

$studentData = array();

foreach($cursor as $row){

   foreach($row->marks as $item){
    $result = array();
    $result ['subject'] = $item->subject;

    $result ['mark_secured']  = $item->mark_secured;

    $result ['Grade']     = $item->Grade;

    $studentData[] = $result; 
  }

  }

  echo json_encode($studentData);
```